# How to properly declare variables in scala to prompt Users input?

Tags: scala

I just get my hand on Scala on these days, I have a situation where I have 3 variables, and all these 3 variables need to prompt users' input. Blatantly, I wrote this way

```
val A = readLine()
val B = readLine()
val C = readLine()
```

I feel that if I keep this way with a large set of variables, I will be overloaded when maintaining the code, is there anyway I can shortened this chunk into something like

```
val (A, B, C) = (readLine(), readLine(), readLine())
```

or using array for shorter?

Any help is appreciated